# The Pull Request merge commit has unexpected first parent (VSTS)

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

In our system, every PR triggers a PR validation build on a build controller, where:

1. The build controller workspace is updated to origin/master
2. The PR is merged
3. The PR merge commit is checked out
4. The build is triggered

My understanding is that the PR merge commit will have the following two parents:

1. origin/master
2. The last commit in the PR

However, this is not always the case!

Please, observe:

**Get Sources build step output**

```
2018-11-27T15:39:21.3096756Z    bf58eb148..b00bf1df0  master               -> origin/master
2018-11-27T15:39:21.3099964Z  * [new ref]             refs/pull/3987/merge -> pull/3987/merge
2018-11-27T15:39:31.3045930Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/pull/3987/merge
2018-11-27T15:39:32.8530040Z Previous HEAD position was ce1d1c670... Merge pull request 3982 from wfm/work/pbi476403 into master
2018-11-27T15:39:32.8530496Z HEAD is now at 81317ea59... Merge pull request 3987 from onboarding/476463-Automation_GettingStarted_Performance_Improvements into master
```

The PR 3987 contains only one commit:

[image]

From which my logic tells me that:

1. At that moment origin/master = b00bf1df0
2. The local PR merge commit, i.e. pull/3987/merge = 81317ea59
3. The first parent of pull/3987/merge would be origin/master, i.e. b00bf1df0
4. The second parent of pull/3987/merge would be the last commit of the PR, i.e. b7d9617fc

Now I will go the build controller and check there:

[image]

I see that the first parent is not b00bf1df0, but some other commit 959f488bb.

I do not understand how this is possible. Can anyone explain?